# for/and/so: Are all three of those conjunctions equally acceptable in this situation?

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions, subordinate-clauses, coordinating-conjunctions, subordinators

I’m trying to connect two different clauses, each with its own subject and tensed verb, but I don’t know when to use one conjunction instead of another to do so. To summarize, I know that:

1. And = addition
2. For= the cause ; a bit archaic
3. So = the result

But in this context, are *for* and *and* and *so* all equally acceptable with slightly different meanings?

1. Last month, my credit card bill was high, **for** I owed more than $700. 
   ( My credit card bill was high **because** I owed more than $700.)
2. Last month, my credit card bill was high, **so** I owed more than $700. 
   ( **Because** my credit card bill was high, I owed more than $700.)
3. Last month, my credit card bill was high, **and** I owed more than $700. 
   ( My credit card bill was high **and [equally]** I owed more than $700.)

What sorts of situations govern when you should use any particular one of those instead of either of the other two? Does it matter if it’s writing or speaking? Is there a difference in register, like in the pub or in the courtroom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***for*** is probably most correct here, but is a dated usage.

***so*** is used when introducing a result, but the amount *isn’t* a result.
***and*** introduces an additional concept, but the amount *isn’t* an additional concept, it is an exposition of the first part of the sentence.

What a native speaker might actually say is: “My credit card bill was high this month, to the tune of $700!!

Comment: So then, "so" is not possible? In # 2, I was wondering if having a high bill meant that the result was me owing $ 700.

Comment: @meepyer No. It is not a result at all. The high bill is $700, and $700 is the high bill. Compare "He hit me, **so** I hit him" = He hit me **and, as a consequence**, the result of that action was my hitting him."

Comment: Though (2') << Last month, my credit card bill was high. So I owed more than $700. >> might be considered conversationally acceptable nowadays, where 'so' is broadened such that the string is a paraphrase of << Last month, my credit card bill was high ... /: / – I owed more than $700. >>

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I could agree with: “Last month my credit card *balance* was high, so I owed more than $700.

Comment: If your balance is high, surely that means you're in credit. This _is_ possible with a reversal from a previous month, etc.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Is this an AmE/BrE thing?  See for example: https://www.creditkarma.com/credit-cards/i/high-credit-card-balance

Comment: Perhaps it's a product divide. 'Temporary high balances: 
FSCS protects temporary high balances in your bank account, building society account or credit union account of up to £1million for 6 months. The protection begins from the date the temporary high balance is credited to an individual depositor's account, ' [[FSCS](https://www.fscs.org.uk/making-a-claim/claims-process/temporary-high-balances/)]. A difference in meaning (a high true value or a high absolute value of a debt) to be wary of.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Yes. With a deposit account a high balance means you’ve got a lot of money. With a credit account a high balance means you owe a lot of money.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason the sentence had me doing a double-take. It makes sense now.